# Castle Windsor Interface resolution via reflection

Tags: reflection, castle-windsor

I have encountered a small problem when trying to resolve an interface in castle using reflection.

Lets say I have an interface `IService`, and can resolve it like this:

```
 var service = wc.Resolve<IService>();
```

This works as expected, but I want to call the method through reflection and can do so like this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(WindsorContainer).GetMethod("Resolve",new Type[] {});
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(IService));
var service = generic.Invoke(wc,new object[]{});
```

This also works fine.  Now lets imagine I want to select the type to be reloved using reflection.

```
Type selectedType = assembly.GetType("myProject.IService")
```

And then try to invoke it like this:

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(WindsorContainer).GetMethod("Resolve",new Type[] {});
MethodInfo generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(selectedType);
var service = generic.Invoke(wc,new object[]{});
```

I get a Castle error:

```
"No component for supporting the service myProject.IService was found"
```

The Type of selectedType appears to be correct, but there is a problem.

Does anyone know what I can do to invoke the resolve method correctly?

BTW `MakeGenericMethod(typeof(selectedType)` does not compile.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Why do you even need MakeGenericMethod?  [Castle has a non-generic Resolve method](http://www.castleproject.org/container/documentation/v1rc3/manual/windsortypedocs/Generated_IWindsorContainer.html#IWindsorContainer_Methods4)

Does just `container.Resolve(selectedType)` work?

Comment: container.Resolve(selectedType) produces the same error.  Thanks for the pointer about the non generic method.

Answer (score 1):

Did you register a component for `IService`? This works just fine for me:

```
using System;
using Castle.Windsor;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace WindsorInitConfig {
    [TestFixture]
    public class ReflectionInvocationTests {
        public interface IService {}

        public class Service: IService {}

        [Test]
        public void CallReflection() {
            var container = new WindsorContainer();
            container.AddComponent<IService, Service>();

            var selectedType = Type.GetType("WindsorInitConfig.ReflectionInvocationTests+IService");
            var method = typeof(WindsorContainer).GetMethod("Resolve", new Type[] { });
            var generic = method.MakeGenericMethod(selectedType);
            var service = generic.Invoke(container, new object[] { });
            Assert.IsInstanceOfType(typeof(IService), service);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had a component registered in a .config file, which produced the behaviour above.  In the end I added a component using the AddComponent method, which did work, but defeated the object somewhat. Now I can resolve using the String Key, but have a dependency in code, not in the config.